# Mysql changes data type when i change hostname to AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Just gonna say, im very new to mysql so bear with me. Im working on a project that has already been progressed on. When i try to open the mysql file i was sent it works fine and everything is in order. but when i make a new instance using the same code and schemas but on a different hostname other than localhost (i intend to use RDS so i change hostname to AWS link), the data types in the columns ALL change from int to bigint on their own and cause compatability errors. Is there a way i can disable this kind of action? i run everything on workbench

The database works fine on localhost but when i change to RDS host i get error 3780: Referencing column 'a' and referenced column 'b' in foreign key constraint 'c' are incompatible. The fact that it works on localhost makes me sure its not a design issue

Comment: There's nothing that I can think of in RDS to explain the behavior you are reporting, but should mention the versions of MySQL that you are running locally and in RDS.  I would note, also, that if "all" the columns were changing as you describe, there would be no incompatibility because they would "all" be bigint.  Do you get this error when attempting to initially load the dump file onto the RDS instance, or at a later time?  If later, then please describe the circumstances and what you are doing when the error occurs.